# I can't use spaces with the if statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, input, spaces

I'm trying to make a program like clever bot but when the uses spaces it won't work. Please help.(:

```
@echo off
set text=Hello
:start
cls
echo %text%
set /p input=:
if %input%==a b set text=It worked
goto start
```

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes:

```
@echo off
set text=Hello
:start
cls
echo %text%
set /p input=:
if "%input%"=="a b" set text=It worked
goto start
```

It will also handle null input.

Mona

Comment: Thank you so much. That got answered fast.